# Column not getting filled in after putting several conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, fillna

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong. I am using a databases with three columns. I am trying to filter through one of my columns, named 'POT_SALES, using a condition and fill in an empty column, called 'PROFILES', with 5 different profile types.

Here is the code I've been using so far:

```
for c in df_seg.POT_SALES:
    if c >= 8.0:
        df_seg.PROFILES.fillna('Ambassador')
    elif c >= 6.0:
        df_seg.PROFILES.fillna('High-Potential')
    elif c >= 4.0:
        df_seg.PROFILES.fillna('Starters')
    elif c >= 2.0:
        df_seg.PROFILES.fillna('Competitors')
    else:
        df_seg.PROFILES.fillna('Haters')
```

After I run it in Jupyter, the data frame doesn't change at all. What do you recommend me to do?

I was trying to fill empty columns, after filtering the data, but nothing happened

Comment: By default, most operations in pandas behave in a functional manner meaning they produce a new object rather than causing side-effects. Some of them allow for `in_place` flag which overrides this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one approach, using [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html?highlight=cut#pandas.cut)

```
# using cut, BIN the values per the IF criteria
# -1 and 99 are just the lower and upper bounds
# labels to assign when value falls within the corresponding bins

df['profile']=pd.cut(df['POT_SALES'], 
                     bins=[-1,2, 4, 6, 8,99],
                     labels=[ 'Haters','Competitors','Starters','High-Potential','Ambassador'],
                     include_lowest=False,
                     precision=0,
                     right=False,
                     ordered=True,
      )
df
```

```
    POT_SALES   profile
0           0   Haters
1           1   Haters
2           2   Competitors
3           3   Competitors
4           4   Starters
5           5   Starters
6           6   High-Potential
7           7   High-Potential
8           8   Ambassador
9           9   Ambassador
```